# Positioning sticked (fixed) element relatively

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I positionate a `fixed` element at the left side of the `div` with processing resize events?

Here's example: http://jsfiddle.net/yHErk/10/

Now on my screen resolution `.skicked` is right at the left side of `.container`. But if I'll simply resize the result window, it'll change. Is there a simple way to do that thing I want?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Currently your `.sticked` div has no relative parent to hold it so it is moving according to the re-size.

Add `.sticked` `div` inside the `container div.`

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #dedede;
    padding: 10px; position:relative
}

.sticked {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: -50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
}
```

​**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yHErk/11/)**

Comment: Nope. You made it absolute, but it must be fixed to stay at one place when scrolling.

Comment: In that cas it happens for everyone coz fixed div is nowhere related to any parent div. Check this site they have fixed div on right side and when you re-size the browser it comes over the content, jus like how it is happening in your sample. http://www.gobdg.com/position-relative-z-index-ie-bug